# How can I find in Graylog 4.0 log record with unique combination of two fields?

Tags: graylog

So, I've forwaded the auth logs of my web application to graylog, and now I want to implement some alerts for brutefroce.
Each record sent from the webapp to Graylog contains some information, among which username and hashed password.
I would like to find with a query for the alerts that count the unique combination of the fields login and hashed_password.

I know how to setup the alerts, but can't find a working query.

For example, I've this logs:

```
... login=foo hashed_password=XXXX ...
... login=foo hashed_password=XXXX ...
... login=foo hashed_password=XXXX ...
... login=foo hashed_password=YYYY ...
... login=foo hashed_password=ZZZZ ...
... login=foo hashed_password=AAAA ...
... login=foo hashed_password=AAAA ...
... login=foo hashed_password=BBBB ...
```

I would like to find a query print only one time each combination of this two fields. I've tried with many tries but without success.
From the log aboce, it should print only:

```
... login=foo hashed_password=XXXX ...
... login=foo hashed_password=YYYY ...
... login=foo hashed_password=ZZZZ ...
... login=foo hashed_password=AAAA ...
... login=foo hashed_password=BBBB ...
```

Some of the queries I've tried are the following:

```
auth:"error" AND distinct(login+hashed_password)
auth:"error" AND count(distinct(login+hashed_password))
auth:"error" AND count(login(hashed_password))
```

I'm running on a graylog 4.0 version and Elastic Oss 7.10, all the servers are Centos7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:
I just grouped the result from the query by IP Source and logins, then I added this condition to create events:

`card(hashed_password) > 15`

Same things with similar kind allarms, where i put these conditions:

`[count(login) > 100 AND [card(IP_Source) == 1 AND card(login) == 1 AND card(hashed_password) == 1]]`

Where I grouped by the same voices.

Answer (score 0):

First, the bad news. Graylog does not support Elasticsearch v7.11. 7.10 is the latest supported version.

Second, more bad news. Graylog does not support any of the functions you are trying to use in queries. The supported syntax can be found here: https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/searching/query_language.html?highlight=syntax#search-query-language

You can do some of what you want using dashboards. I would also suggest trying aggregation events (Alerts/Events) to alert you to when these conditions occur.

Comment: For Elastic: I've  looked wrong, we have the .710 OSS version, updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a GROK pattern to filter out only the messages with the informations you are looking for (login and pass).

GROK patterns allowed me to trim logs, deleting all the unhelpful informations and keeping only what I needed under a specific field name, which is extremely useful when you need to monitor suspicious log-ins.

For example: in your case, you could create a field named *"login_failed_foo"* and then set an alarm when the number of occurencies of this field reaches a certain point.